# SQL column data inside an if

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use the data of a mysql column inside an "if" but unfortunately I don't know how to do and I think i'm searching with the wrong terms.

So here is my code :

```
$reqcle=$bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM clebeta WHERE cle='".$clebeta."'");
    $reqcle->execute();
    $countcle=$reqcle->rowCount();
    $askcleutil=$reqcle->fetchAll();
    //on vérifie d'abord que la clé existe en base de données
    if($countcle == 1){
        //on continue le traitement et on vérifie si la clé n'est pas déjà utilisée
        if($askcleutil[2] == "0"){
            //on continue le traitement et on vérifie l'existence du pseudo minecraft en base de données
        } else {
            //on affiche que la clé est déjà utilisée
        }
    } else {
        //on affiche une erreur : clé inexistante
    }
```

It's in my last if : if($askcleutil[2] == "0")

I want to test the value of the 'active' column inside my DB but I don't know how to do

Sorry if i'm not clear but I don't know how to explain this clearly

Comment: You'll need to loop through everything that you've fetched using a `for` loop.

Comment: `$askcleutil` is an array of arrays. you're doing `Array == "0"` which is never going to work... `$askcleutil[2]['active']` would work, if you only wanted to test that one record.

Comment: I'll try this Marc, thank you ! :)

Comment: I think what you want is to do $askcleutil['active'] instead of [2]['active'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `selectAll()`, so you miss your loop.

> Returns an array containing all of the result set rows (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

You need like this:

```
foreach ($askcleutil as $row) {
    if ($row['a_col_name_of_your_selected_row'] == 0) {
       // Handle
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but all my next "if" will have to be in this foreach no ?